# Right way to store/trac visits of an item - job board

Tags: php, mysql

im developing a job board site, where i have the following tables:

- Cv (Curriculum)
- Jobs
- Users

I want to produce the follow information:

- How many users visit this Job
- How many users visit my CV
- How many cv i visited
- How many jobs i visited

My obviously thinking is to created a table for example: log_jobs (id, job_id,user_id) and a log_cv (id,cv_id,user_id)

With this i can produce the information i want.

But the question is:

- We are expecting a lot of traffic, with this aproach i can have mysql performaces issues?
- A table with a real big size (imagine, each visit in a job two queries, each visit in a CV, two queries, this just to log the action) will be a problem? or mysql can handle with a real big table ??

Tkz in advice

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Big tables arn't a problem with MySOL. All you need to do is create the necessary indexes on each table and you won't have a problem.

If you only want to display totals you can also create a table to store only 'hits' eg log_views(cv_id, view_count) and then increment view_count every time a cv is viewed.

Comment: My ideia isnt just the totals, but know who is watching what, but my fear is about the size which will be a lot of traffic... but tkz :)